# How to quickly launch a playlist from the home screen in ios?

Tags: ios, shortcut, music.app

I want to have a "shortcut" on the home screen that launches
the music app and starts playing a specific playlist.
Can this be done?

I did some research and it seems like Launch Center Pro *could* do the trick, except the music app is not supported.
I also found an old blog post that mentions the use of URL schemes for ecoute (music player) but it seems outdated as well.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly overkill for just this one task, but [Workflow](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/workflow/id915249334?mt=8) can certainly do this--there's already a workflow in its Gallery that does this, so you won't even have to write your own. And you'll probably find other cool stuff to do with it too ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Launcher with Notification Center Widget by Cromulent Labs](https://appsto.re/us/iLR81.i)
Will launch any playlist from Notification Center.